Flask сайт недоступен из интернета
Пишу свой сайт на Flask, закидываю его на свой сервер и когда запускаю с помощью app.run(debug=True, port=80, host="0.0.0.0"), то все прекрасно работает как по белому ip, так и из локальной сети, но как только я захотел запустить его так:
from waitress import serve
serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=80)

То стал получать:

Но только в том случае, если захожу по белому ip, если заходить из локальной сети, то все будет работать как должно. Никаких ошибок при этом на сервере не возникает.
p.s. Больше кода оставить не могу, в нем конфиденциальные данные.

Я нашел решение. Дело было в том, что flask при автоматическом перезапуске скрипта при изменении не смог найти waitress, после его установки и перезапуска сервера все заработало корректно
